# jQuery - how to get to the heavily nested element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get value or change checked attribute that lies here:

html body div#container.user_view table tbody tr td#cright ul#all_charts_container li.chart_container div.header input#stat_view_1.checkbox

I'm having a trouble getting to it. Is there some easy way?

If I move this element to `<body>` then I can access it no problem.

Answer (score 4):

`$("input#stat_view_1.checkbox")` that not the selector you want?

Comment: OK, I have <input type="checkbox" name="chart_checkbox_select_all" class="checkbox" id="chart_checkbox_select_all" value="chart_checkbox_select_all" /> <label for="chart_checkbox_select_all">Select all</label> is there a direct way to say if it was clicked or not? I have $("#chart_checkbox_select_all").click(
  function()
  {
   alert('Clicked');
  }
);  but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm I even deleted class="checkbox" from it, but still it's doesn't work. Firebug doesn't say anything.

Comment: $("#chart_checkbox_select_all").change( function() { alert('Clicked'); } );

Comment: I think there is something else wrong. Like not having jquery loaded. But I checked, I have 1.4.4 loaded. Checked this code in separate file - it works. In symfony project it doesn't.

Comment: ahh, i'm not very experienced in symfony. Must be a jquery issue.

Comment: will let you know if I figure it out

Comment: OK, if I wrap it like that:$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#chart_checkbox_select_all").change( function() { alert('Clicked'); } ); 
});
    then it works.

Answer (score 3):

Since it has an id, just:

`alert($("#stat_view_1").attr("checked"));`